# Integral Inequality for function in $W^l_2$ space

Tags: sobolev-spaces, integral-inequality

For a function $u(x_1,x_2)$ of compact support in $E_2$, the following inequality holds : $$ \iint_{-\infty}^{\infty} u^4 dx_1 dx_2 \leq \iint_{-\infty}^{\infty} u^2 dx_1 dx_2 \iint_{-\infty}^{\infty} \nabla^2u dx_1 dx_2$$
I read this in Fluids by Ladyzhenskaya, but I couldn't follow the proof. Can someone give a simple proof for this or provide the name of the above lemma so that I could search for the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of an [interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_inequality), often referred to as [Ladyzhenskaya's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladyzhenskaya%27s_inequality), which is a special case of the [Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality).

A simple proof can be done in the three-dimensional case, as by Sobolev's inequality $W^{1,2} \hookrightarrow L^6$ and hence by Hölder's inequality

$$\|u\|_{L^4}^4=\int |u| |u|^3 \leq \|u\|_{L^2} \|u\|_{L^6}^3 \leq C\|u\|_{L^2} \|u\|_{W^{1,2}}^3.  $$

You should be able to find a proof in any book that investigates the Navier-Stokes equations as Ladyzhenskaya's inequality is essentially in proving the existence of weak solution. For example you can consult

- 'Topics in Nonlinear Analysis' by Luc Tartar, Lemma 2 on page 35.